# Handling a method with an optional argument followed by a list of keyword arguments

Tags: ruby, arguments, splat

I want to pass an optional argument (any datatype, even a Hash) followed by a list of keyword arguments (which can be empty) to a method.

This is what I got:

```
def my_method(subject = nil, **options)
  [subject, options]
end
```

The method output is as expected in the following cases:

- nothing

  ```
  my_method()
  # => [nil, {}]
  ```
- a subject

  ```
  my_method('foo')
  # => ["foo", {}]
  ```
- a literal subject with options

  ```
  my_method('foo', bar: 'bar')
  # => ["foo", {:bar=>"bar"}]
  ```
- a `Hash` as subject with options

  ```
  my_method({foo: 'foo'}, bar: 'bar')
  # => [{:foo=>"foo"}, {:bar=>"bar"}]
  ```
- no subject, only options

  ```
  my_method(bar: 'bar')
  # => [nil, {:bar=>"bar"}]
  ```

When passing a `Hash` as subject and no options, the desired outcome is:

```
my_method({foo: 'foo'})
# => [{:foo=>"foo"}, {}]
```

But I get the following; I don't get the correct subject:

```
my_method({foo: 'foo'})
# => [nil, {:foo=>"foo"}]
```

Is `my_method(foo: 'foo')` equivalent to `my_method({foo: 'foo'})`? Any ideas on how I could get the desired outcome?

Comment: I updated in my answer why it got assigned to second argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, you have `**options` as an argument which do not have any default value & first argument have default value. So understand following **single argument case**,

Whenever single argument is passed it is tried to assign to second argument (as first one is holding default nil) & if it fails due to type mismatch then it assign to first argument. That's how `my_method(4)` works.

Now Suppose you have single argument passed as hash, which match to assign to 2nd argument then of course it get assigned to second argument & first is set default nil.

If you want to make it work, then you can do following,

```
> my_method({sd: 4}, {})
 => [{:sd=>4}, {}]
```

Or you can provide argument name while passing,

```
> my_method(subject: {sd: 4})
 => [{:sd=>4}, {}]
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is a limitation of how Ruby passes arguments. It can't tell the difference between `my_method({foo: 'foo'})` and `my_method(foo: 'foo')`

Why not hack around it with this?

```
if subject.is_a?(Hash) && options.empty?
  subject, options = nil, subject
end
```

This assumes that `subject` shouldn't be a hash though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I need to pass a hash to `subject` sometimes.

Comment: @Taschetto Ok... but how would you distinguish a nil subject and just options from a Hash subject and no options?

Comment: `my_method({foo: 'foo'})` should be a hash subject and no options; `my_method(foo: 'foo')` should be a nil subject and just options. But maybe I'm getting it wrong.

Comment: @Taschetto I'm pretty sure that's a limitation of Ruby. It cannot distinguish between those two cases. I would just make `subject` non-optional in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best answer but you can try with [keyword argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) :

```
def my_method(subject: nil, **options)
  [ subject, options ]
end
```

Then

```
my_method(subject: {foo: 'foo'})

=> [{:foo=>"foo"}, {}]
```

### Alternative  :

You can use

```
my_method({foo: 'foo'}, {})
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Yes, that works. But in my case I'd have to refactor a large number of method calls. I need to maintain the method interface.

Comment: @Taschetto then my_method({foo: 'foo'}, {}) can be a solution ?